# Phonegap won't pull latest version

Tags: android, git, cordova, github, phonegap-build

I'm making some changes to a test app to see how it works, git + phonegap, and for some reason I dont think phonegap is pulling the latest code. I can see the changes on github, here's the public test: https://github.com/xxAndreixx/prueba

I'm making the changes to the index.html file in the www folder, and I'm trying to install the app after I pull the code and rebuild, on an Android phone and however I can't see the changes when running the app; idk if I'm running the wrong commands on git. What I do is: 1) git commit -m "msg" 2) git push -u master origin

IDK where I'm failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TIL:** don't be stupid and follow the correct order while in the `ROOT`.

Answer (score 0):

@Andrei,
are you pressing the [Update Code] button?

[image: Update Code Button]

Comment: Oh yes I do, of course. Not sure which index file to edit though; I'm modifing the one from the www folder, should I update the one from the platforms folder?

Comment: Yes. This is a problem. These articles should help. If you are using *Phonegap Build* then the index.html is in your www directory, and so is your config.xml. In Phonegap CLI, the index.html is in the www directory, and the config.xml is one directory closer to the root. **Phonegap Build FAQ** https://build.phonegap.com/faq **Cordova/PhoneGap Version Confusion** http://devgirl.org/2014/11/07/cordovaphonegap-version-confusion/